# C++: can C++11 move semantics avoid pointers in shared-ownership cases?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

I have a `Bar` class and some instances of a `Foo` class, which contain lists of `Bar` objects. I want any changes to the underlying `Bar` objects to change the `Bar` in the `Foo`'s lists (so copies are out of the question).

Is it possible to avoid using pointers with C++11 move semantics? Or is this kind of shared ownership one of the cases when pointers are a necessity?

Pointer implementation:

```
struct Bar
{
public:
    int someProperty;
};

class Foo
{
public:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Bar>> barList;
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Bar> pBar(new Bar);

    Foo fooA;
    Foo fooB;

    fooA.barList.push_back(pBar);
    fooB.barList.push_back(pBar);

    pBar->someProperty = 5;

    return 0;
}
```

For example, could there be a separate class which owns the `Bar` objects, and then the `Foo` objects have lists of references to them? Like `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper(Bar)> barList`? Or would pointers be preferred in this case?

I've been advised that pointers are wildly over-used in C++ and references should be used wherever possible.

Comment: If you have *shared* ownership then you should be using a *shared*_ptr

Comment: You can't really have containers of references, not directly anyway. You might be able to use e.g. [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) and [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref)? But `std::shared_ptr` was *made* for shared ownership.

Comment: It is raw **owning** pointer which should be avoided. pointer may be fine (`observer_ptr` may be better).

Comment: Side note: Please get used to `auto pBar = std::make_shared<Bar>()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you could create an architecture where you have a separate owner for the `Bar` objects and the `Foo` objects only hold lists of pointers, such an architecture has nothing to do with move semantics and only concerns whether this ownership model makes sense in your domain.

But if you create such a model, use raw pointers, or a really dumb pointer wrapper if you fear confusion. References don't work in lists, and `reference_wrapper` doesn't buy you anything.

If you instead think that it makes sense for the `Foo` objects to actually have shared ownership of the `Bar` objects, then go with containers of `shared_ptr`.

Either way, move semantics have nothing to do with it.

Comment: So there's no way I can have instances of `Bar` owned by some `BarRegister` without necessarily using pointers to `Bar` inside `Foo`? I.e. there's no way references can be used in this case? Also, if there were a `BarRegister` responsible for the `Bar` objects, would it make more sense to use `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`, if you could guarantee that every `Foo` would be destroyed before the `BarRegister`?

Comment: There's no way to use references, and no point in doing so. Raw pointers or a simple observing_pointer wrapper perfectly communicate the intention, except perhaps for non-nullability, which a wrapper could enforce. And if you have one BarRegister that owns the Bars, then unique_ptr is the right choice.

Answer (score 1):

Your question at present betrays an oversimplification of your "foo/bar" example. Namely, it ignores this question:

Do you intend for `Foo` to *own* the `Bar` objects it contains?

Not every class that has a pointer/reference to an object is intended to own that object. In many cases, you can structure code so that ownership is maintained by the relationships between classes. For example, if `Foo` were created by some `FooMaker` overseer object, that object could be responsible for creating (and owning) the `Bar` objects stored in those `Foo` objects. Or `Bar` objects could be owned by some other system.

If each `Foo` instance is never going to outlive the other owner of its `Bar` instances, then `Foo` shouldn't need to own them. This is why talking about "foo" and "bar" isn't helpful. Without the context, we can't say what the right relationship here ought to be.

If it is your intent for `Foo` to directly control the lifetime of the `Bar` objects stored within it, then it should use a smart pointer. If however, it is your intent for `Foo` not to control the lifetime of `Bar` objects stored within it, then it should not use smart pointers. The idiomatic way in C++ to represent this is [with a naked pointer](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md) (just because people say that something has been "overused" does not mean that you should stop using it entirely) or a reference. Since you need to store them in a `vector`, a pointer is more appropriate (possibly decorated with [GSL's `not_null`](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Ri-nullptr) for clarity).